# Jetpack Compose Deeplink Conditional navigation

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, deep-linking, jetpack-compose-navigation

im facing the problem that i do not see any good sample on conditional navigation using jetpack compose. Especial when it comes to Deeplinks where the App supports deeplinks to specific screens based on some preconditions. How do you guys impl. those scenarios?

In an App i work on we're using some Application-Viewmodel where we check if an user is logged in or not, which works fine when just launching the App from the launcher.

The Problem is that if you fire an deeplink the check if a User is logged in or not becomes ignored and the user may see content which i don't want to happen.

If you can share your solution that would help a lot.

Thanks

Update: In general its good practice to separate those scenarios by using a NavHost for each, but i cant find any Informations if that's the way to got here

Also I've run some simple tests to see how the Compose Framework behaves. When the App gets launched the start destination gets triggered and all works as expected, the check if a user is Logged In or not trigger the next destination. In case of an Intent the onNewIntent|onResume seems to override any other state and triggers the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know how your app navigation looks like, but I can give you my approach with a single activity and fragment navigation.

1. Retrieve the deeplink in the main activity and pass it to the view model(ideally it should be done in seperate activity/fragment).
2. Launch the sign in fragment where authentication is done.
3. In your home fragment, check if there is a deep link available in the view model and handle it. This can be done in onCreateView but since the check of deeplink's null value is done on every recreation, it may be better suited to put it in onAttach()
4. Reset the deep link in the view model, so it's not processed multiple times.

Comment: In my understanding the problem is that you cannot intercept the deeplink that easy. I've tried an approach where i intercept the deeplinks on activity #onResume for example and rewrite the URL so that i can navigate to some composeable where i check for some conditions. That centralizes the problem. That approach needs some more more thinking but seem to point into a direction i like.


currently we check on each of those leave for the conditions which feels pretty wrong as it duplicates quite some code and also makes the navigation graph more complex